# UITableView deselectrow not working in ipad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have table View in which i want to add image to cell on selection and change the image to seleced cell if new cell is selected

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {

          cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Activity.png"]; 

        }


  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {


       [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

       cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


       cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Activity2.png"]; 
        NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

  }
```

here is the code what i want i have given in my opinion

```
        if (indexPath.row==0) {

       cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Activity2.png"]; 
       NSLog(@"Cell Clicked row  0");


       if(indexPath.row==1){


        NSLog(@"Cell Clicked row 1 in 0");

        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Catalog"];

      }

      }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {

    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Catalog2.png"]; 
    NSLog(@"Cell Clicked row  1");


    if(indexPath.row==0){


        NSLog(@"Cell Clicked row 0 in 1");


        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Activity"];

    }


}
```

new code added that how i want images on cell when new cell is selected.

Comment: What is the issue ? What you mean by deselectrow not working ?

Comment: yes i am assigning image to Selected row 0 Activity2.png and when i select row 1 i want that row0 should have Activit,ong and row 1 should have Row2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop thru all the other TableViewCells and set their image , try this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [aTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:indexPath.section]];

        cell.imageView.image=nil;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];

}
```

Comment: i want that row one is selected it should show Activity2.png and if row 2 is selected then it may show Catalog2 and row1 show Activity not activity2

Answer (score 6):

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

use this one it will work

Answer (score 0):

I have set delegate, datasource  to self and used following code for both iphone and iPad

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgres.jpeg"];

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"];

}
```